# How to compare two arrays if they have similar values or not in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am comparing the API response with database fields. I have stored the API response in one array and database field in another

```
API_Response = "2451423412", "2453565", "23563425645", "43252436", "4676345"

Database_Response = 768567, 4534534, 32451423412, 6978657, 2453565 , 23563425645, 43252436, 4676345
```

In the 'Database__Response' array i have 8 values out of which 5 values are similar to 'API_Response' array.

I want to remove the double quotes from 'API Response' and then compare if all the values in 'API_Response' array are available in 'Database__Response' array

Comment: Please try something on your own, and come up with a more specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: Those are not arrays, not even valid Ruby objects.

Comment: @sawa Technically speaking... Yes they are and Yes they are. Ruby allows your to forgo the square brackets when defining a literal `Array`. That being said I would never recommend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
API_Response.all? { |number| Database_Response.include?(number.to_i) }
```

`all?` returns as soon as it finds a `number` that is not included and therefore might be faster than checking all numbers.

Depending on the size of `Database_Response` it might make sense to translate that array into a `Set` first. Furthermore, you might want to improve performance by using your database to solve this problem instead of loading all records into memory first.

Comment: This is `O(N²)` while `(API_Response.map(&:to_i) - Database_Response).empty?` is `O(N)`.

Comment: Which is literally `O(N)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it helps you check this

To remove the double quotes from API Response just do this

```
            API_Response = API_Response.map(&:to_i)
```

Now to compare both API_Response and Database_Response

```
        result =  API_Response & Database_Response
```

this will compare both arrays and gives you common values from both the arrays

```
       result = [2453565, 23563425645, 43252436, 4676345]
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @santosh dadi. This piece of code really helped to remove the double quotes and compare the array values. But one more question arises here for me,  what if one array has characters and another array has integers for ex: API_Response = "1,0,0,1,1" and Database_Response = "true, false, true, false, true, false, false". Here 1 refers to true and 0 refers to false in 'API Response'. I want to compare these two arrays

Comment: @SagarKalshetti Convert the strings to the same format first. `API_Response.gsub('1', 'true').gsub('0', 'false').gsub(',', ', ')`. Keep in mind that those still aren't arrays but just strings.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array of strings to array of integers. Then sort the array to compare the arrays

```
API_Response.map(&:to_i).sort == Database_Response.sort
```

This will return true only if both the response arrays are equal after sorting

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if all the values of `API_Reponse` are availabe in `Database_Response` you should do the following:

```
API_Response = API_Response.map(&:to_i)
(API_Response - Database_Respone).size.zero?
```

The result of the second LOC will determine if all the values of `API_Response` are present in `Database_Response`

Comment: I'd replace `.size.zero?` with `.empty?`, but otherwise a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple `true`/`false` result I recommend taking a look at the [*Set*](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class. It contains some useful methods to check if one set is a superset or subset of another set.

```
require 'set'

API_Response.map!(&:to_i)
Set.new(API_Response) <= Set.new(Database_Respone)
#=> false
```

Keep in mind that when creating a set from an array duplicated values are removed automatically.

**References:**

- [`Array#map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map-21)
- [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i)
- [`Set::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new)
- [`Set#<=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-3C-3D) (alias for [`Set#subset?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subset-3F))

Comment: Didn't know about the `<=` feature. That's really something.